# Resizable jQuery - detect where scroll starts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building custom calendar and I have the following issue: since I have to create different events on that calendar, that start and end on certain dates, and I need to resize them (left and right), I would need to know if I am starting that resize from the left side or from the right side, so I know how to set those dates.

Basically, it doesn't select the proper dates when I resize from start and when I resize from the end.

**EDIT:** My draggable elements also get some sort of top/left values that mess up everything, and I cannot resize it to left more than their start width (to the right side it does what it should).. It is reducing width (- 47px) instead of adding that width.

This is the code I have for resizable now:

```
$(".draggable").resizable({
        classes: {
            "ui-resizable": "highlight"
        },
        containment: '.calendar-row',
        grid: [47, 10],
        handles: 'e, w',
        resize: function (event, ui) {
            lastEvent = event;

        },

        start: function (event, ui) {
            uiEvent = true;
            $( event.originalEvent.target ).one('click', function(e){ e.stopImmediatePropagation(); } );
        },

        stop: function (event, ui) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                uiEvent = false;
            }, 300);
            $( event.originalEvent.target ).one('click', function(e){ e.stopImmediatePropagation(); } );

            if(isChrome || isEdge)
            {
                var resizedDate = new Date($(lastEvent.toElement).attr('data-date'));

                // left to right
                if(ui.size.width > ui.originalSize.width)
                {

                    console.log($(lastEvent.toElement).attr('id'));
                    console.log($(lastEvent.toElement).attr('data-date'));

                }
                else{
                    var elemFromPoint = document.elementFromPoint(lastEvent.pageX, lastEvent.pageY).previousElementSibling;
                    console.log($(elemFromPoint).attr('id'));
                    console.log($(elemFromPoint).attr('data-date'));
                }
            }

            if(isFirefox)
            {
                var resizedDate = new Date($(lastEvent.target).attr('data-date'));
                $(lastEvent.target).hide();

                // left to right
                if(ui.size.width > ui.originalSize.width)
                {
                    var elemFromPoint = document.elementFromPoint(lastEvent.pageX, lastEvent.pageY);

                    console.log($(elemFromPoint).attr('id'));
                    console.log($(elemFromPoint).attr('data-date'));
                }
                else{

                    var elemFromPoint = document.elementFromPoint(lastEvent.pageX, lastEvent.pageY).previousElementSibling;

                    console.log($(elemFromPoint).attr('id'));
                    console.log($(elemFromPoint).attr('data-date'));
                }
                $(lastEvent.target).show();
            }

        }
    });
```